# "gradlew setupEclipse" throws an error?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, gradlew

- Operating System: OS X ELpitan
- Eclipse version: Eclipse Oxygen Java EE IDE

Hi, I am following https://github.com/TEAMMATES/teammates/blob/master/docs/ide-setup.md guide to setup Eclipse IDE for a project from Github. I have successfully installed the required plugins mentioned in the guide.But when i run `./gradlew setupEclipse` it throws the following error
[image]

So, I ran `gradlew tasks` the following output was given:

[image]

Can someone explain me why is this happening and how can I successfully set up the IDE , please?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: As you see in the `gradlew tasks` output, there is no task named anything with "eclipse". This is odd, I do see many more tasks when I run `gradlew tasks`. Are you sure you are in the right directory and the `git cone` has completed? Maybe try cloning again?

Comment: @Robert Apologies for posting pictures of the code. Yes, I am in the right directory. I even tried setting up the project in a windows machine and I still get the same error. Any ideas? Thanks